# Симуляция физики на стороне сервера

Tags: c#, unity3d, сервер, asp

Есть ли какая библиотека на C# для симуляции физики ?

Предположим, что есть не большая игра на движке Unity, например сцена и в ней один персонаж. Естественно для мультиплеера всю физику, столкновения надо расчитывать на стороне сервера.

Из этого всего родилась такая мысль, а что, если взять какую нибудь библиотеку, в которой есть возможность создать сцену со всеми препятствиями (на подобии ThreeJS на javascript), и когда игрок передает команды клавиш WSAD на сервер, то мы двигаем нашего персонажа в "серверной сцене", и отдаем координаты. Или может можно как то из Unity сцену портировать на сервер )

Пока просто интересуюсь данным вопросом, направьте пожалуйста в нужном направлении.

Comment: "естественно для мультиплеера всю физику, столкновения надо рассчитывать на стороне сервера" - это вам кто такое сказал?

Comment: Верно, можно и p2p, но это 100% читеры будут )

Comment: Причем здесь читеры, просчитывайте бОльшую часть на клиенте и передавайте на сервер. А нечестивых игроков можно и по-другому ловить. Да и причем здесь p2p?

Comment: Пускай даже так, что мешает использовать саму юнити для симуляции физики на стороне сервера?

Comment: Вот мне кстати очень интересно, как использовать юнити на стороне сервера, есть идеи ?

Comment: p2p при том что можно выбирать одного клиента из группы подключеных и просчитывать столкновения на его клиенте, вот тут и всплывают читеры, а как проверить не честных игроков без симуляции физики/столкновений я не представляю к сожалению (

Comment: Зачем тут p2p, каждый игрок просчитывает физику, связанную с собой, а сервер все это вместе собирает и синхронизирует игроков. На самой юнити физика просчитывается так же, как и на клиенте, слишком сложно объяснить это в комментариях.

Comment: Так а что будет когда юзеры напишут мод, который большинство установит, получится так что будут комнаты где все юзеры с модом, вот и получится что сервер будет думать что все делается правильно, ведь у всех все одинаково. По поводу юнити на сервере была мысля собрать сцену для linux, но не придумал как к ней обращатся через asp net

Comment: Если вам не сложно, можете в ответ описать метод запуска юнити на стороне сервера ?

Comment: Сервер ничего не будет думать, геймплейные моды для мультиплеера - это та ещё странность. Пускай даже моды официально разрешены - сделайте такой API для модов, который будет проверять их валидность,

Comment: Мне не то, что бы сложно - я не занимаюсь разработкой серверной части игр, все, что я вам выше описывал - чистая теория, а найти какой-нибудь гайд для этого не составит труда :)

Comment: Большое спасибо, навели на мысль, попробую покопать в эту сторону )

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста, если вы найдёте ответ на свой вопрос и если вас не затруднит - опубликуйте его здесь - это поможет другим разработчикам :)

Comment: Обязательно опубликую

Comment: Это должен быть реально мощный сервер, иначе он будет тормозить - физику считать очень затратно по времени. Обычно физику делают на клиенте, а на сервер передаются только позиции игроков для синхронизации и их действия. Те же хедшоты невозможно было бы поставить, если бы расчет выстрелов был на сервере, из-за задержки между сервером и клиентами.

Comment: Физика на сервере должна быть примитивной. По поводу синхронизации, тут надо предугадывать действия, есть даже статья на хабре по этому поводу. Считать физику на клиенте это 100% читерство, так как в любом случае можно подделать свою позицию. Достаточно того, что все пользователи всегда будут знать позиции других, что уже само по себе не правильно. Такой подход можно было бы применить в играх на консолях, так как там читерство минимальное.